# Headers for force download of apk file

Tags: php, android, header, download, apk

I'm doing a script that increases the counter for an APK file's download then sends the file to the browser for download.

Here's what I have:

```
<?php
    $file = "android.apk";

    function force_download($file){
    header("Pragma: public", true);
    header("Expires: 0"); // set expiration time
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($file));
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
    die(file_get_contents($file));
    }

    force_download($file
```

The problem is that with a browser like firefox, it downloads but it is like 'android.apk - 0 bytes'. So it essentially, it does not download the file's contents.

What might I be doing wrong? A solution for this?

**IMPORTANT**: It has to work on mobile.

);

Comment: make sure that file_get_contents($file) can read file, test it with out any headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've realized that I don't need to use complex header info expecially if the script will be moved from server to server where the .apk mime type is not native and may therefore be hard for a novice to set up.

A simple redirect will do:

```
$file_name = $_GET['f']; //$_GET['f'] has the link to the file like http://mydomain.com/file/android.apk


//Do database query or increase download counter

header('location: '.$file_name);
```

Voila! I have increased the counter and the download will be pushed to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I've never accessed a .apk link that didn't force a download, so I'm not sure what the need for a force download is on that. As far as incrementing the counter, I would probably just link to a page that forwards to the apk file after the counter has been done.

For instance link someone to: getapk.php?apkid=1

Then on getapk.php do something like this:

```
 $update = mysql_query("UPDATE apps SET downloads...");
 if ( $update ) { header("Location: appname.apk"); }
```

Of course that leaves out a lot of details, but if you need help with anything else I'd be happy to provide more details.